# JBPN Workflow and % 100 task completion

Tags: jbpm

I have unique requirement for JBPM process work flow. Is there any way to compute % compete for entire work flow.  One way, I was thinking about computing this is to assign weighted to all nodes at begin of workflow when process is started and report the % when each node is complete.

There are following scenarios that need to be accounted when considering the % of node competed.

1)  Decision Node
2)  Async sub-process

```
<Tab>
  <process-definition>
    <start-state> 
      <transition to='s' />
    </start-state>
    <state name='s'>
      <event type='node-leave'>
        <action class=EndActionHandler'>
    <weight>10</ weight > 
    </action>
      </event>
      <transition to='t'/>
    </state>
    <state name='t'>
      <event type='node-leave'>
        <action class=EndActionHandler'>
    <weight>90</ weight > 
    </action>
      </event>
      <transition to='end'/>
    </state>
    <end-state name='end' />
  </process-definition>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Wit the approach you suggested things would get messy with workflows that have cyclical parts.

Comment: Which version of jBPM is this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the easiest way to do this would be to do this within the action classes themselves.

For example, you could create a flow variable that you persist to the jBPM context that keeps track of how the process instance is in the process.